# How to print the values of slices

Tags: arrays, go

I want to see the values which are in the slice. How can I print them?

```
projects []Project
```

Comment: besides `fmt.Println(projects)`?

Comment: Also: []Projects is a slice, not an array: http://golang.org/blog/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: Why did you all gave me -1 ?

Comment: @fnr sorry, but the reviewers probably felt the question was a easily solved by the doc. I have updated my answer to show it isn't always as obvious though. You can leave your question, it is a valid one.

Comment: @fnr - a -1 on this site means the question: "does not show research effort; it is unclear or not useful". So I see you tagged your question "go" and "arrays" and want to know "how to print" them. If I go to Google.com and search "go programming language tutorial arrays" I find a number of resources including [this](http://www.golang-book.com/6/index.htm) which looks like it might help. So if this does help, it shows you didn't research it much before posting. If this doesn't help, you need to call out sites like this you searched and explain why it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292187/12817546.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

You can try the `%v`, `%+v` or `%#v` verbs of [go fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

```
fmt.Printf("%v", projects)
```

If your array (or [here slice](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)) contains `struct` (like `Project`), you will see their details.
For more precision, you can use `%#v` to print the object using Go-syntax, as for a literal:

```
%v  the value in a default format.
    when printing structs, the plus flag (%+v) adds field names
%#v a Go-syntax representation of the value
```

For basic types, `fmt.Println(projects)` is enough.

---

Note: for a slice of pointers, that is `[]*Project` (instead of `[]Project`), you are better off defining a `String()` method in order to display exactly what you want to see (or you will see only pointer address).
See this [play.golang example](http://play.golang.org/p/5y2IIAuek_).

Comment: You could also use a `for` loop to to see the values which are in the slice `[]Project`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292187/12817546.

Answer (score 49):

For a `[]string`, you can use [`strings.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join):

```golang
s := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
fmt.Println(strings.Join(s, ", "))
// output: foo, bar, baz
```

Answer (score 45):

I prefer `fmt.Printf("%+q", arr)` which will print

```
["some" "values" "list"]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XHfkENNQAKb

Comment: How to get array with comma separator ??

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ If you find short solution please add it as an answer to this question. I’m betting that is what most people are looking for.

Comment: strings.ReplaceAll(fmt.Sprintf("%+q", arr), "\" \"", "\",\"")

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to see the values of an array without brackets, you can use a combination of `fmt.Sprint()` and `strings.Trim()`

```
a := []string{"a", "b"}
fmt.Print(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprint(a), "[]"))
fmt.Print(a)
```

Returns:

```
a b
[a b]
```

Be aware though that with this solution any leading brackets will be lost from the first value and any trailing brackets will be lost from the last value

```
a := []string{"[a]", "[b]"}
fmt.Print(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprint(a), "[]")
fmt.Print(a)
```

Returns:

```
a] [b
[[a] [b]]
```

For more info see the documentation for [strings.Trim()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim)

Comment: fmt.Printf(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprintf(a), "[]") is missing a paren on the right hand side. Thanks for the snippet.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to view the information in a slice in the same format that you'd use to type it in (something like `["one", "two", "three"]`), here's a code example showing how to do that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    test := []string{"one", "two", "three"}     // The slice of data
    semiformat := fmt.Sprintf("%q\n", test)     // Turn the slice into a string that looks like ["one" "two" "three"]
    tokens := strings.Split(semiformat, " ")    // Split this string by spaces
    fmt.Printf(strings.Join(tokens, ", "))      // Join the Slice together (that was split by spaces) with commas
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vOF6xZ__Otr)

Comment: Wrong. "%q" is hex format.

Comment: only works for strings with one word.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a package named Pretty Slice. You can use it to visualize slices, and their backing arrays, etc.

```golang
package main

import pretty "github.com/inancgumus/prettyslice"

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 9, 5, 6, 4, 8}
    odds := nums[:3]
    evens := nums[3:]

    nums[1], nums[3] = 9, 6
    pretty.Show("nums", nums)
    pretty.Show("odds : nums[:3]", odds)
    pretty.Show("evens: nums[3:]", evens)
}
```

---

**This code is going produce and output like this one:**

[image]

---

For more details, please read: https://github.com/inancgumus/prettyslice

Answer (score 4):

`fmt.Printf()` is fine, but sometimes I like to use [pretty print package](https://godoc.org/github.com/kr/pretty).

```
import "github.com/kr/pretty"
pretty.Print(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `for` loop to print the `[]Project` as shown in @VonC excellent answer.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Project struct{ name string }

func main() {
    projects := []Project{{"p1"}, {"p2"}}
    for i := range projects {
        p := projects[i]
        fmt.Println(p.name) //p1, p2
    }
}
```